# Issue with sap.m.PDFViewer (1.48) on mobile devices

Tags: pdf, sapui5

I am developing a Master-Detail application which should show an embedded PDF in its detail view. The project is based on UI5 version 1.48, so the new [PDFViewer](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.PDFViewer) control can be used.

In desktop mode, everything works as expected:
[image: PDFViewer on Desktop]

But on a mobile screen, PDF is not showing properly:
[image: PDFViewer on Mobile]

The data source property binding at the PDFViewer is done by OData path.

```
<FlexBox id="fbPDFViewer"
    direction="Column"
    renderType="Div"
    class="sapUiSmallMargin">
    <PDFViewer id="idPDFViewer"
        source="{myModel>/myPDFUrl}"
        title=""
        busy="true"
        showDownloadButton="false"
        height="700px"
        width="95%"
        loaded="onPDFLoaded"
        errorMessage="{i18n>notFoundText}"
        errorPlaceholderMessage="{i18n>notFoundText}">
    </PDFViewer>
</FlexBox>
```

Even the SAP sample for embedded usage [doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0F6ZQ.png) on mobile devices.

Comment: Related [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/1759).

Answer (score 2):

According to the source code (1.48), the viewer renders its PDF document directly in the app / iframe [**only when**](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/5c5206f4786ac3a0be96f9a94d2448166e3b371d/src/sap.m/src/sap/m/PDFViewerRenderer.js#L46) ..:

1. The source is valid

   - It's [coming from the same domain](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.PDFViewer/events/sourceValidationFailed)
   - It has a [valid URI format](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/2b57525d81f3097e40eb6c88d8c42294fc7de7cc/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/core/library.js#L1509-L1515)
2. UI5 thinks the user is using a desktop computer (`Device.system.desktop` returns `true`) **or** the `displayType`<sup>[api](https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.PDFViewer/methods/setDisplayType)</sup>, available [since 1.58](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/825cae63028c2333e1f4f49d77e41daccc57f7b7), is set to `Embedded`.
3. UI5 detects that the user agent (browser) has a certain type of [PDF plugin enabled](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/5c5206f4786ac3a0be96f9a94d2448166e3b371d/src/sap.m/src/sap/m/PDFViewer.js#L134). Currently, there are no known **mobile** browsers which support displaying PDF documents directly in the page.

The steps 2 and 3 explain why the PDF is not rendered on a mobile device even if the source is valid. In such cases, I guess the only option is to provide a download option instead of trying to render the PDF forcefully in the mobile app.

Answer (score 1):

You can use nabi.m.PDFViewer from the the nabi.m library. It works cross device, even on iOS (where you typically don't have the adobe PDF plugin). For details see https://github.com/nzamani/ui5-nabi-m

There you will find also how to try it out on localhost. I have also added some detailed instructions for deployment of the library to NW ABAP as well as SAP CP.

You can find live demos at http://ui5lab.io/browser/#/Samples/nabi.m/Sample/nabi.m.PDFViewer.PDFViewer and http://ui5lab.io/browser/#/Samples/nabi.m/Sample/nabi.m.PDFViewer.InPagePDFViewer

Open the two links on your iOS device or any other device to see how it looks like.

Answer (score 1):

On mobile devices (smartphones and tablets), the PDF viewer control renders a toolbar with the title and a download icon, which behaves as a standard device/browser file link. We've made this note in Fiori Design Guidelines 1.48 and we'll add it to the SDK documentation.

(More in [openui5 issue 1759 on GitHub](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/1759))

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your responses and hints...

- Installing an Adobe Acrobat viewer on the mobile devices was not an option here.
- Source of the PDF had same domain like app itself and had a valid URI format too

Due to project timeline in meantime I decided to fall back to a solution that SAP provided with it's "Paystub" (Fiori 1.0). Therein they're using a 3rd-Party control for displaying PDF's which unfortunately has an overhead of code and implementations steps but it works (with minor issues only) perfect on desktop devices as well as on mobile devices.

So far, this is workaround solved my requirement. 
Thanks.